# Copy contents from Directory1 to Directory 2 Replacing Duplicates

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal

### Story:

I basically have a "git repositories" directory on my computer.  I also am working on a workflow project for the productivity application called Alfred.  Alfred, like many other applications, require the files to be within their library to function properly.  **I want to have a bash command that will copy the files from the "Alfred Directory" -> "git\ repositories/repository_name" replacing all the old files with the newly updated ones.**  This way I can push my changes up to Github.  I would basically alias this in the terminal to make it easy to repeat.

---

## What I am trying to accomplish:

**I want to have a bash command that will copy the files from the Directory1 -> Directory2 replacing all the old files in Directory2 with the newly updated ones from Directory1.**

- Directory1 = file1, file2 (new)
- Directory2 = file1, file2 (old)

**If there is a better way to do this please share!**

---

### What I know:

**bash:**

cp -r ~/path/to/Directory1/ . ~/path/to/Directory2

---

**Now how do I get it to replace the old ones?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to try `rsync`

```
rsync -avz ~/path/to/Directory1/ ~/path/to/Directory2/
```

Comment: Could you explain rsync -avz in your own word? Just curious! Thanks for the help!

Comment: `-v` means verbose, the command will print out what are synced over.  `-z` means compress, `-a` is a short form for a few other flags, it equals to `-rlptgoD`, you can `man rsync` to get the meaning of each individual flag.

Comment: Also, a couple other things:
 
When I do this, it adds a copy of the entire Directory1 inside Directory2.
 
And, lets say I delete file1 in Directory1. It does not remove it from Directory2.

Comment: I guess you didn't add `/` after the directory name, instead of  `Directory1`, please use `Directory1/`